# How to change the code below, to support Locale

Tags: android

The Code snippet below, taken from "Utility.Java" file of "Udacity Sunshine App". The "Date" data fetch from the server, and display on this fashion.

I want to change the code in android studio, in order to support Locale. And finally return name of the day and month with different language. Help me please?

```
static String formatDate(long dateInMilliseconds) {
    Date date = new Date(dateInMilliseconds);
    return DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);
}

// Format used for storing dates in the database.  ALso used for converting those strings
// back into date objects for comparison/processing.
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyyMMdd";

/**
 * Helper method to convert the database representation of the date into something to display
 * to users.  As classy and polished a user experience as "20140102" is, we can do better.
 *
 * @param context Context to use for resource localization
 * @param dateInMillis The date in milliseconds
 * @return a user-friendly representation of the date.
 */
public static String getFriendlyDayString(Context context, long dateInMillis, boolean displayLongToday) {
    // The day string for forecast uses the following logic:
    // For today: "Today, June 8"
    // For tomorrow:  "Tomorrow"
    // For the next 5 days: "Wednesday" (just the day name)
    // For all days after that: "Mon Jun 8"

    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int julianDay = Time.getJulianDay(dateInMillis, time.gmtoff);
    int currentJulianDay = Time.getJulianDay(currentTime, time.gmtoff);

    // If the date we're building the String for is today's date, the format
    // is "Today, June 24"
    if (displayLongToday && julianDay == currentJulianDay) {
        String today = context.getString(R.string.today);
        int formatId = R.string.format_full_friendly_date;
        return String.format(context.getString(
                formatId,
                today,
                getFormattedMonthDay(context, dateInMillis)));
    } else if ( julianDay < currentJulianDay + 7 ) {
        // If the input date is less than a week in the future, just return the day name.
        return getDayName(context, dateInMillis);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, use the form "Mon Jun 3"
        SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
        return shortenedDateFormat.format(dateInMillis);
    }
}

/**
 * Helper method to convert the database representation of the date into something to display
 * to users.  As classy and polished a user experience as "20140102" is, we can do better.
 *
 * @param context Context to use for resource localization
 * @param dateInMillis The date in milliseconds
 * @return a user-friendly representation of the date.
 */
public static String getFullFriendlyDayString(Context context, long dateInMillis) {

    String day = getDayName(context, dateInMillis);
    int formatId = R.string.format_full_friendly_date;
    return String.format(context.getString(
            formatId,
            day,
            getFormattedMonthDay(context, dateInMillis)));
}

/**
 * Given a day, returns just the name to use for that day.
 * E.g "today", "tomorrow", "wednesday".
 *
 * @param context Context to use for resource localization
 * @param dateInMillis The date in milliseconds
 * @return
 */
public static String getDayName(Context context, long dateInMillis) {
    // If the date is today, return the localized version of "Today" instead of the actual
    // day name.

    Time t = new Time();
    t.setToNow();
    int julianDay = Time.getJulianDay(dateInMillis, t.gmtoff);
    int currentJulianDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), t.gmtoff);
    if (julianDay == currentJulianDay) {
        return context.getString(R.string.today);
    } else if ( julianDay == currentJulianDay +1 ) {
        return context.getString(R.string.tomorrow);
    } else {
        Time time = new Time();
        time.setToNow();
        // Otherwise, the format is just the day of the week (e.g "Wednesday".
        SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        return dayFormat.format(dateInMillis);
    }
}

/**
 * Converts db date format to the format "Month day", e.g "June 24".
 * @param context Context to use for resource localization
 * @param dateInMillis The db formatted date string, expected to be of the form specified
 *                in Utility.DATE_FORMAT
 * @return The day in the form of a string formatted "December 6"
 */
public static String getFormattedMonthDay(Context context, long dateInMillis ) {
    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    SimpleDateFormat dbDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Utility.DATE_FORMAT);
    SimpleDateFormat monthDayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd");
    String monthDayString = monthDayFormat.format(dateInMillis);
    return monthDayString;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, for name of the day; SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.US);
            String dayName = dayFormat.format(dateInMillis);
           

            if (dayName == "Monday") {
                return context.getString(R.string.day_name_1);
            } else if (dayName == "Tuesday") {
                return context.getString(R.string.day_name_2);
            } //the others here... // else if (dayName == "Sunday") {
                return context.getString(R.string.day_name_7);
            }else
            return null;

Comment: Please edit that into your question and format it as code

Answer (score 1):

Just add the Locale to to the SimpleDateFormat constructor

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE  MMM dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
return dateFormat.format(dateInMillis);
```

Comment: This only return name of the day and month in English.

Comment: Change the Locale to whatever you want, like Locale.French<br>
If you want the full date you would use
    SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy", Locale.French);

Comment: I want to use Amharic language(Ethiopian Language) as a default.

Comment: You would do the following;

    `Locale am = new Locale("am", "ET");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE  MMM dd", am);
    return dateFormat.format(dateInMillis);`

Please note, that not every device supports the Amharic locale. It also depends on which version Android they are running.

Comment: Thank you for everything! I'll try and inform you.